# How to get the values of each option HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, html-select

I have a form with dropdown, the dropdown values have a correspoding values too. E.g. If the user choose the option 1 in the dropdown, the values under dropdown will be displayed. Now, I want to get the values of div.position for each option and displayed it in a dropdown too.

I tried to get the values, but my JS is not working.

How to do this correctly?

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".job_listings li a div h3").each(function(){
        myArr.push($(this).html());
    });
});
console.log(myArr);
```

HTML:

```
<select class="job_types_select">
<option value="choose-department">Choose department</option>
<option value="facility">Facility</option>
<option value="finance"> Finance</option>
<option value="human-resources">Human Resources</option>
</select>
```

HTML Result:

```
<ul class="job_listings">
    <li class="job_listing job-type-facility post-7747 type-job_listing status-expired hentry" data-longitude="14.5870923" data-latitude="121.063549" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="#>
        <img class="company_logo" alt="">
    <div class="position">
            <h3>Housekeeping Attendant</h3>
            <div class="company"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="location"></div>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="job-type facility">Facility</li>
            <li class="date"><date>4 months ago</date></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="job_listing job-type-facility post-7734 type-job_listing status-expired hentry" data-longitude="14.5870923" data-latitude="121.063549" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="company_logo" alt="">
        <div class="position">
            <h3>Liaison Officer</h3>
            <div class="company"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="location"></div>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="job-type facility">Facility</li>
            <li class="date"><date>4 months ago</date></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS dropdown (1st dropdown)

```
(function($){
    "use strict"
    jQuery(function(){
        var $job_types_select = $('<select class="job_types_select"></select>');
        var $job_types_ul = $('form.job_filters ul.job_types');
        var $job_type_hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="filter_job_type[]"/>');
            $job_types_ul.find('li').each(function(){
                var $li = $(this);
                var label_text = $li.find('label').text();
                var value = $li.find('input:checkbox').val();
                var $option = $('<option></option>');
                $option.text(label_text);
                $option.attr({value: value});
                $job_types_select.append($option);
            });
                $job_types_select.change(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                $('input:hidden[name="filter_job_type[]"]').val(value);
                    var target = $(this).closest('div.job_listings');
                    target.triggerHandler('update_results', [ 1, false ]);
                });
        $job_types_ul.after($job_type_hidden);
        $job_types_ul.replaceWith($job_types_select);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what do mean by "all values for each option" ?is it like this,
Housekeeping Attendant
Facility
4 months ago
or is it just 
Housekeeping Attendant
to be shown in the next dropdown

Comment: No. I want to get the value of div.position for each option values (I updated my question

Comment: that means for example "housekeeping attendant" isn't it

Comment: yes, even the user not choose any option in the dropdown. I want to get all the values of div.position to all options html

Answer (score 0):

You could try the working snippet as shown below,it will definitely work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var myArr=[];
    $(".job_listings li a div h3").each(function(){
        myArr.push($(this).html());
    });
  console.log(myArr);
  console.log("2");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="job_listings">
    <li class="job_listing job-type-facility post-7747 type-job_listing status-expired hentry" data-longitude="14.5870923" data-latitude="121.063549" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="#>
        <img class="company_logo" alt="">
    <div class="position">
            <h3>Housekeeping Attendant</h3>
            <div class="company"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="location"></div>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="job-type facility">Facility</li>
            <li class="date"><date>4 months ago</date></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="job_listing job-type-facility post-7734 type-job_listing status-expired hentry" data-longitude="14.5870923" data-latitude="121.063549" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="company_logo" alt="">
        <div class="position">
            <h3>Liaison Officer</h3>
            <div class="company"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="location"></div>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="job-type facility">Facility</li>
            <li class="date"><date>4 months ago</date></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Your code fetching the innerhtml of the div element is correct,but you have to initialize the array either inside or outside the document.onready but the code `console.log(myArr);`outside the onready will not work in the following 2 cases,
2. **Case -1:** the array is intialized inside the function and the console.log is outside the onready function.An error will be thrown saying that the myArr variable has not been initialized.
3. **Case -2:** The array is initalized before the onready function and the console.log outside the function then the empty array will be shown since it will execute before the onready function

Comment: it's not working in my side, i getting this: Array[0]